# Why my bxCAN peripheral damaged?

Tags: can

I implement a communication between two stm32f4 discovery board. I was trying to get some errors of hcan->Error (ESR in bxCAN) as much as i can to see how STM32 handles CANbus error management.
I shorted one of tranceiver's CAN L to the VDD and VCC respectively and after doing that communication disappeared. I traced one of mcu. It enters init and normal mode well. While transmitting process TEC incrementing and Bus off, error warning and error passive flags set. Last error code indicates bit dominant error.

My tranceivers was working at that time. I used simple board which includes 2xSN65HVD251DR IC, 2x100nf, 2x120 ohm.

NOTE: Damaged bxCAN worked on  LOOPBACK mode.

Comment: Is it permanently damaged now? How are the boards powered up? Different power supplies? Is there a ground between the boards too, or just CANH and CANL?

Comment: @Justme Only related bxCAN (can1), i turned my setup to can2 and didnt get any error.

Answer (score 1):

CAN tranceivers are very robust. You can verify the truth table of the tranceiver using GPIO mode of the STM32.

Increasing `TEC` often means it did not receive an acknowledge bit.
You can find the error code in `CAN_ESR->LEC`.

If you do not enable to loopback mode you will receive *Acknowledgment Error* with only one active node on the bus.